# Восстановление образа диска Acronis на диск меньшего размера

Tags: ubuntu, резервное-копирование, восстановление, системное-программирование

Подскажите пожалуйста, как восстановить образ диска на диск меньшего размера? Используемое место: 15gb. Размер исходного диска: 120gb, целевого: 32gb. На диске Ubuntu, lvm. Либо как сделать образ Ubuntu для диска с меньшим размером? Умею работать с Clonezilla, но это ПО тоже не хочет восстанавливать образ на диск большего размера (с признаком "Не проверять размер диска")

Comment: что значит как? разворачиваете образ и все, не очень понятно где у вас проблема возникла

Comment: @Andrew на этапе восстановления, Acronis не хочет восстанавливать на диск меньшего размера.

Comment: 32гб... вы на флешку развернуться хотите?

Comment: @Andew SSD диск

Comment: `не хочет восстанавливать образ на диск большего размера`. Чего? С каких пор? На меньшего - да. Но на большего - никогда проблем не возникало. Ты что-то не то делаешь значит.

Comment: @donRumata xD Сам не заметил

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете восстановить свою систему на диск с меньшим размером при условии что не будете указывать разметку которая была раньше на большем носителе. Но места должно хватать под ваш образ. Это в целом реально. [Вот](https://forum.acronis.com/forum/acronis-true-image-2016-forum/how-recover-disk-image-smaller-drive-not-clone) есть обсуждение подобной проблемы. Для этого вам нужно при восстановлении указать нужный пункт списка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше вам нужно поменять разметку диска:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[вот](https://kb.acronis.com/content/2770) тут есть туториал как решить вашу проблему.